# How to Define Custom Theano Types Allowing Differentiation

Tags: python, theano

I am trying to follow the documentation to [create a double type](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/type.html) in Theano and implement operations on this type as described [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/op.html). The current state can be found below:

```
import theano

class Double(theano.gof.Type):

    def filter(self, value, strict = False, allow_downcast = None):
        if strict:
            # we need to return a type, but if the value is incompatible raise an exception
            if isinstance(value, float):
                return value
            else:
                raise TypeError('Expected a float!')
        elif allow_downcast:
            return float(value)
        else:
            value_float = float(value)
            if value_float == value:
                return value_float
            else:
                raise TypeError('The double type cannot be accurately represent %s of type %s' % (value, type(value)))

    def values_eq_approx(self, value_a, value_b, tolerance = 1e-6):
        return abs(value_a - value_b) / (abs(value_a) + abs(value_b)) < tolerance

double = Double()

class DoubleAddOp(theano.Op):

    __props__ = ()

    def make_node(self, x, y):
        # check input types
        if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
            x = theano.gof.Constant(double, x)
        if isinstance(y, (int, float)):
            y = theano.gof.Constant(double, y)

        if x.type != double or y.type != double:
            raise TypeError('DoubleAddOp only works on doubles.')

        return theano.gof.Apply(self, [x, y], [double()])

    def perform(self, node, inputs, output_storage):
        x = inputs[0]
        y = inputs[1]
        z = output_storage[0]
        z[0] = x + y

    def infer_shape(self, node, input_shapes):
        return [input_shapes[0]]

    def grad(self, inputs, output_grads):
        return [output_grads[0]*1, output_grads[0]*1]

    def __str__(self):
        return 'DoubleAddOp'

dadd = DoubleAddOp()
```

In order to test the code, I wrote a few unit tests:

```
import theano
import random
import unittest
from double import double, dadd

class TestDoubleOps(unittest.TestCase):

    # the forward pass runs fine ...
    def test_DoubleAddOpPerform(self):
        x = double('x')
        y = double('y')
        z = dadd(x, y)
        f = theano.function([x, y], z)

        for i in range(100):
            x_value = random.random()
            y_value = random.random()
            self.assertAlmostEqual(f(x_value, y_value), x_value + y_value)

    # I am trying to get the gradient computation working here,
    # this is what I have so far:
    def test_DoubleAddOpGrad(self):
        x = double('x')
        y = double('y')
        z = dadd(x, y)
        gx = theano.tensor.grad(z, x) # <---
        gy = theano.tensor.grad(z, y)
        f = theano.function([x, y], [gx, gy])

        for i in range(100):
            x_value = random.random()
            y_value = random.random()

            print(f(x_value, y_value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, when testing the gradient computation, I get the following error at the marked line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/theano/double-type-python/double_test.py", line 32, in test_DoubleAddOpGrad
    gx = theano.tensor.grad(z, x)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 436, in grad
    if cost is not None and cost.ndim != 0:
AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

It seems that this is a problem of the double type defined above. However, the type itself is scale, so I should be able to compute the gradients using `theano.tensor.grad`. Unfortunately, I could not find an example demonstrating the gradient computation on custom types and wasn't able to learn more about the `ndim` attribute ...

Any help is appreciated; thanks!

**Update.** When trying to trick `theano.tensor.grad`, e.g. by explicitly setting `z.ndim = 0`, the problems go on, e.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/theano/double-type-python/double_test.py", line 33, in test_DoubleAddOpGrad
    gx = theano.tensor.grad(z, x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 477, in grad
    g_cost = _float_ones_like(cost)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1340, in _float_ones_like
    dtype = x.type.dtype
AttributeError: 'Double' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

So it seems that I am missing something fundamental here and the defined Double type is missing several different type-specific information that is not mentioned in the documentation.

**Update.** After re-reading the documentation and looking into Theano's source code, the right question to ask is: Is it possible to define custom (non-tensor) types in Theano that allow differentation?

**Update.** Based on nouiz' answer, I am running into the next problems - these are giving me the impression that gradient computation is not intended for non-TensorType types:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/theano/double-type-python/double_test.py", line 32, in test_DoubleAddOpGrad
    gx = theano.tensor.grad(z, x)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 477, in grad
    g_cost = _float_ones_like(cost)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1344, in _float_ones_like
    return tensor.ones_like(x, dtype=dtype)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 2377, in ones_like
    return fill(model, ret)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 604, in __call__
    node = self.make_node(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/elemwise.py", line 577, in make_node
    inputs = list(map(as_tensor_variable, inputs))
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/tensor/basic.py", line 171, in as_tensor_variable
    "Variable type field must be a TensorType.", x, x.type)
theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Variable type field must be a TensorType.', DoubleAddOp.0, <double.Double object at 0x7fb623a5b9b0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. You can. We do that ourself for sparse variable and GPU variable.

But you hit corner cases theano.grad() wasn't made to support. Mostly, it expect an ndim parameter and a dtype parameter. Adding the dtype="float64" parameter should work around that.

ndim one is easy to fix in Theano with this diff:

```
diff --git a/theano/gradient.py b/theano/gradient.py
index 6d6fbaf..3b4d706 100644
--- a/theano/gradient.py
+++ b/theano/gradient.py
@@ -433,7 +433,7 @@ def grad(cost, wrt, consider_constant=None,
                          "cost is NaN because " +
                          cost.type.why_null)

-    if cost is not None and cost.ndim != 0:
+    if cost is not None and getattr(cost, 'ndim', 0) != 0:
         raise TypeError("cost must be a scalar.")

     if isinstance(wrt, set):
```

For the dtype, it is more complicated as we use it at many places for verifycation purpose (you can't take the grad of integers for example) and also to init the chain of gradient (or you can pass it via the known_grad parameter)

UPDATE: The new error can be fixed with this bigger diff:

```
diff --git a/theano/gradient.py b/theano/gradient.py
index 6d6fbaf..6a9ec03 100644
--- a/theano/gradient.py
+++ b/theano/gradient.py
@@ -433,7 +433,7 @@ def grad(cost, wrt, consider_constant=None,
                          "cost is NaN because " +
                          cost.type.why_null)

-    if cost is not None and cost.ndim != 0:
+    if cost is not None and getattr(cost, 'ndim', 0) != 0:
         raise TypeError("cost must be a scalar.")

     if isinstance(wrt, set):
@@ -1341,7 +1341,7 @@ def _float_ones_like(x):
     if dtype not in tensor.float_dtypes:
         dtype = theano.config.floatX

-    return tensor.ones_like(x, dtype=dtype)
+    return x.ones_like(dtype=dtype)


 class numeric_grad(object):
diff --git a/theano/tensor/var.py b/theano/tensor/var.py
index 2ecb9f0..6b08a45 100644
--- a/theano/tensor/var.py
+++ b/theano/tensor/var.py
@@ -727,6 +727,9 @@ class _tensor_py_operators(object):
     def zeros_like(model, dtype=None):
         return theano.tensor.basic.zeros_like(model, dtype=dtype)

+    def ones_like(model, dtype=None):
+        return theano.tensor.basic.ones_like(model, dtype=dtype)
+
     def cumsum(self, axis=None):
         return theano.tensor.extra_ops.cumsum(self, axis)
```

You need to add the ones_like method to your Variable like this:
    def my_ones_like(model, dtype=None):
        return ...
    double.ones_like = my_ones_like

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So I applied the fix above and also added "dtype='float64'", which works around the two mentioned problems. However, I do not have the impression that gradient computation is intended to work with non-TensorType Types at a as_tensor_variable call. I will update my question with the corresponding stack trace. Could you also provide a link to the implementations where you a doing something similar for sparse variables (as you mentioned)? Thanks!

Comment: I forgot, for sparse matrix, it only work if the cost is a tensor. This can be fixed with a bigger diff that I added to my answer. You also need to add the method ones_like() to your class. I give indication for this too. By implementing a new subclass of Variable would be better, but I don't find documentation about that.

Comment: So as I see it, the new diff only makes sense if I derive the double type from theano.tensor.TensorType. But when deriving from theano.tensor.TensorType I do not need the diff as it also works without. However, then I run into problems when e.g. implementing a multiplication gradient operation `return [inputs[1]*output_grads[0], inputs[0]*output_grads[0]]` as the multiplications seem to cause problems. Overall, it doesn't seem to be a very fruitful path - maybe I will learn something from the Sparse Tensor code or go without Theano. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: We didn't implement that case well, but I think it isn't hard to fix. It will be probably easier in the long run for you to work with theano and have many features we already provide. Inheriting from TensorType isn't a good idea. We never inherited from Types and you will probably hit subtle bugs. Can you make a new Type, put the code in a github repo/gist and email Theano-dev about that? It will be a better place to help implement that. Another safer work around is to create ops that convert from your new type to TensorType and make sure the cost is a TensorVariable.